# Numeric computations are not performing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a form which utilizes some checkbox inputs with fixed values and a text 'number' input which should be calculated against an hourly rate.

The idea is that we can select pre-set values and display the total including the number of billable hours times the hourly rate.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var origsum = 0;
    var newsum = 0;
    var tax = 0.06;
    var hourly = 250;
    var tothours = 0;
    $('.cost').click(function() {
        var total = parseInt($('#total').val());
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            sum = total + parseInt($(this).val());
        } else {
            sum = total - parseInt($(this).val());
        }

        $('#total').val(sum);
    });
        $('.tax').click(function() {
            var total = parseInt($('#total').val());
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                origsum = sum;
                newsum = total + (tax * parseInt(sum));
            } else {
                newsum = total - (tax * parseInt(sum));             
            }
            $('#total').val(newsum);
    });

    var prevCount = 0;
    var newCount = 0;
    $(document).on('keyup mouseup', '.rate', function() {
        newCount = parseInt($('.rate').val());
        total = parseInt($('#total').val());
        if(newCount > prevCount) {
            $('.cost').each(function() {
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    sum = total + hourly;
                    $('#total').val(sum);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $('#total').val($('.rate').val() * hourly);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.cost').each(function() {
                if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    sum = total - hourly;
                    $('#total').val(sum);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $('#total').val($('.rate').val() * hourly);
                }
            }); 
        }
        prevCount = parseInt($('.rate').val());
    });
});

</script>
```

The best way to explain it is by example, so I created this fiddle which includes the script and html:

https://jsfiddle.net/dfkw4ggt/4/

As you'll see when you poke around (thanks in advance, btw!), it's all fairly well working until we start adding/clicking in the text/numeric field.

Any advice and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated as I've about exhausted my researching this and would love to get it working.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The only problem that I've noticed is the inaccuracy of `float` calculations. Is that what you're trying to fix ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's my take, and my opinion.

I think you should have a Sub-Total, Total, and Tax. (You could still hide these fields from the end users and only show the "Total")

You can also simplify your code a bit to make it easier to find errors.

Take a look at this [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5ckrprt/3/), where I changed your JS code and added sub/tax/total. Notice how, if there are errors in the calculations, it will be easier to find now.

The JS:

```
var taxRate = 0.06;
var hourly = 250;

// we really only need one event listener for the whole page
$(document).on("change", "input", updateTotal); 

function updateTotal() {
    var runningTotal = 0;

    // find all checked cost fields
    $(".cost:checked").each(function(){
      runningTotal += parseInt($(this).val());    
    });  

    var billableAmount = parseInt($(".rate").val()) * hourly;

    runningTotal += billableAmount;

    $("#subtotal").val(runningTotal);

    var tax;
    if ($(".tax").prop("checked")) {
      tax = runningTotal * taxRate;
    } else {
        tax = 0;
    }

    $("#taxAmt").val(tax);

    $("#total").val( runningTotal + tax );

}
```